# How can I automate an desktop App (java based - jnlp) in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, child-process, appium-desktop

I tried to automate a java-based desktop application with nodejs, but I didn't do much.

The application is of jnlp type (Java Network Launch Protocol). I managed to open the application using the child_process module,

```
    const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c','./app/test.bat']);
   
    let exec = require('child_process').exec
    exec("./app/test.bat", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
         console.log(stderr);
         return;
    }
    // Done.
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

but I don't know exactly how I could interact with it. I read something about using (selenium + winium.desktop.driver), but it wasn't very accurate and I didn't succeed.can you tell me if there is a module for a specific driver. Or if someone tried something similar?